# Split string by delimiter by using vectors - how to split by newline?

Tags: c++, gcc, csv

I have function like this (I found it somewhere, it works with `\t` separator).

```
vector<string> delimited_str_to_vector(string& str, string delimiter)
{
  vector<string> retVect;
  size_t pos = 0;

  while(str.substr(pos).find(delimiter) != string::npos)
  {
    retVect.push_back(str.substr(pos, str.substr(pos).find(delimiter))); 
    pos += str.substr(pos).find(delimiter) + delimiter.size(); 
  }

  retVect.push_back(str.substr(pos));

  return retVect;
}
```

I have problem with splitting string by "\r\n" delimiter. What am I doing wrong?

```
string data = get_file_contents("csvfile.txt");
vector<string> csvRows = delimited_str_to_vector(data, "\r\n");
```

I'm sure, that my file uses `CRLF` for new line.

Comment: Did you read the file in binary mode?  If you read the file with text translation, then you should only need to look for `'\n'`.  You can easily find out what you have by dumping out the `data` string in hex from your program.

Comment: If you want help with a problem you should always tell us what that problem actually is. What goes wrong? What does happen? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to read the file line by line, which:

> Extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n' ...) If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it.

Perhaps you are already reading the file through a function that removes line endings.

Comment: I found it. My function for reading file removed my line endings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you open your file in text mode, i.e., you don't mention `std::ios_base::binary` (or one of it alternate spellings) it is likely that the system specific end of line sequences is replaced by `\n` characters. That is, even if your source file used `\r\n`, you may not see this character sequence when reading the file. Add the `binary` flag when opening the file if you really want to process these sequences.